# Is the group of rational numbers linear over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Is the additive group of rational numbers isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ for some $n$?

Comment: What have you tried? Or a deeper question, if you'd rather: Why do you think this might hold? (Sorry, it is just this seems almost homework-esque, and then I wondered why you might think that it is so...)

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not residually finite.

Comment: @SteveD It isn't? Why not?

Comment: @user1729: I prefer not to provide too many details here, since (as you noted) this smells a lot like homework, but you might consider what finite quotients $\mathbb{Q}$ could have. (An interesting side note that I cannot refrain from mentioning: all *proper* subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ are residually finite.)

Comment: @SteveD I figured if they would use the theorem that you are getting at, the lecturer will smell a rat...I thought that $\mathbb{Q}$ could have finite cyclic quotient. Maybe I should think some more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to a finite group is trivial (its image is divisible and finite). Hence, also every homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to a subgroup of a product of finite groups, a so-called [residually finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group) group, is trivial. But $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ embeds into $\prod_p \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Answer (score 2):

I will post my indicated answer above, still leaving out a few details (in the very real case this is homework).

First, $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is a residually finite group.  The easiest proof I know of is as follows: pick an element $I\neq A\in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$.  Then $A-I$ is a non-zero matrix, with a nonzero entry $a_{ij}$ somewhere in the matrix. Pick a prime $p$ not dividing $a_{ij}$, and notice that $A$ remains non-trivial under the projection $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow GL(n,p)$.

OK, so we know $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is residually finite, and of course subgroups of r.f. groups are r.f., so it suffices to show $\mathbb{Q}$ is *not* residually finite.  But that's easy: $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have any finite quotients, because it is a divisible group, and finite groups are never divisible.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Consider a homomorphism $\phi\colon \mathbb Q\to GL(n,\mathbb Z)$.
Let $q\in\mathbb Q$ and $A=\phi(q)$.
Let $m\in\mathbb N$.
Then we obtain a homomorphism $\bar f\colon \mathbb Q\to G(n,\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$, a finite group. Let $N=|G(n,\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)|$.
Then $\bar f(q)=\bar f(\frac qN)^N=1$, i.e. $A\equiv 1 \pmod m$. Since $m$ was arbitrary, $A=1$. 
In other words, $f$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: You use $\phi(1)=1$, which isn't the case a priori.

Comment: D'oh, of course $\phi(0)=1\ne\phi(1)$.